ExperienceBundle The devName of an existing route can’t be changed
Deploying an ExperienceBundle from DEV Org to CI org via devops procedures
Get this error:
Help_Center1 ExperienceBundle The devName of an existing route can’t be changed. 
Revert the devName of the f04b12d0-f447-4ba5-9605-f7591546101d route back 
to its original value and try again

The error message isn't terribly helpful as to which route (there are dozens) is affected.
Why is this happening and how do I resolve this?

To figure out which route was involved amongst the many :

...
routes/messages
routes/myAccount
routes/newsDetail
routes/questionDetail
...

I downloaded the ExperienceBundle metadata into my IDE and did a search on the error message UUID f04b12d0-f447-4ba5-9605-f7591546101d.
Not surprisingly, this was a custom page I added to my Experience site



Org
Api Name




DEV
my_name__c


CI
My_Name__c



How it got to be this way (mixed case) I have no idea as that custom Experience page was added over a year ago (V57) and the error got picked up when I was deploying other elements of an Experience Bundle at V60.
Since you can't change the api name of a page in Builder, there are several workarounds

Refresh your sandbox from PROD to get the proper ApiName My_Name__c
Delete the page from the sandbox and add it back with the proper API Name My_Name__c. You'll need to deploy the deleted page (route) as well as the new page (route)
If using some DevOps tool (we use Gearset), exploit the ability to coerce strings from one value to another using pattern match.  With Gearset, you define this through their feature called Environment Variables. Other tools may have equivalent solutions. Opted for this solution

